# vps web hosting performance?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, web-hosting

I'm confused about a

```
1 vCore
2,4 GHz
2 Go RAM
SSD 10 Go
Local Raid 10
```

vps capabilities!! Can i use this vps for hosting 4 websites with no problem. To be more specific one of the websites will have at least 1000 visit per day.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can not tell you the answer directly without knowing the details (how your websites are working).

You start with something small and increase the specs, add more servers, and optimize while your websites are growing.

Comment: yes of course, all my websites are made with node.js, one of them have many users but the others no. I wanted to know if this vps can handle it for 3 or4 months. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AhmedCommando Still nowhere enough information. "1,000 visits" could mean 1,000 pageviews, or it could mean 100,000 pageviews. Your code could be elegant and fast and return responses in 50ms, or it could be horrible and slow and return responses in 30s. You might or might not have caching, optimized SQL queries, etc. That's just scratching the surface, and that's why we can't answer this sort of question.